# How do I generate a GUID in an EFI application?

Tags: guid, uefi

I'm writing a small EFI application that oversees deployment of new computers, and among other things prepares the harddisk with a minimal partition table and a rescue system.

Now I'd like to generate random UUIDs for the partition table and partition IDs, but to my astonishment there doesn't seem to be a readymade UUID generator in the standard set of protocols available.

Have I overlooked something here? Which algorithm has the best chance of giving me unique IDs if I don't have a reliable system clock yet, but I have the EFI random generator protocol available?

Comment: A v4 GUID is essentially 122 random bits, plus 6 bits to indicate that we're dealing with a v4 GUID, so it's easily generated if you have access to a (good, non-pseudorandom!) RNG (`EFI_RNG_ALGORITHM_RAW` should do, if the hardware isn't broken).

Answer (score 1):

A GUID is only statistically guaranteed to be unique if generated to a specific algorithm. For UEFI, that means following [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) to generate a time-based UUID *but* with `TimeLow`, `TimeMid` and `TimeHighAndVersion` in little-endian byte order. This is also the format used by Microsoft.

There are tools that will generate conformant GUIDs for you.
The [Online GUID Generator](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx) is one. Another is the not-very-maintained-but-sort-of-useful [EDK2 UEFI Driver Wizard](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-share/tree/master/DriverDeveloper/UefiDriverWizard), a Python-based GUI application that auto-generates the boilerplate for new edk2 modules.

The linux command line utility `uuidgen` command does *not* generate conformant GUIDs, since the timestamp is encoded big-endian.

Comment: Clearly this makes it problematic when you don't have access to a valid clock. On the positive side, if you are using it only for partitioning, the risk of clashes is pretty minimal. You should be reasonably safe if you set the node fields appropriately and generate the timestamp randomly, but making sure you only pick a value earlier than, say, the application build date. Alternatively, use edk2's `EmbeddedPkg/Library/VirtualRealTimeClockLib`.